# How do I version my data in my datawarehouse?

Tags: powerbi, data-warehouse

I'm running into problems due to the tight coupling between my DataWareHouse (DWH) table structure, and my PowerBI data model and reports. Everytime we make a change int he DWH, our PowerBI model breaks (since it depends on the DWH tables/columns etc.). We solve it by timing PowerBI releases at the same time (or just after) the DWH change. This is a manual process I'd like to automate (go to CI/CD), and hence decouple the data engineering for the DWH from the PowerBI development.

I come from a software world we're I'd solve this by running multiple versions of my API (for a while), where the old version stays available until all clients/users have migrated their implementation. But I can't find any good resource on how this is commonly adressed in the data world. What would be the common way(s) to adress this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split your warehouse into 2 instances, a production and development one. When you change something, do it on the development instance. Create a development PBI workspace that holds the same PBI reports, which connects to the dev data and test until you are sure that it doesn’t break. Then roll out the change to the production instance and production report workspace.

Also research more on the keyword “data contract”. I think it may be related to your requirements here